# Mail an asp.net page from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, sendmail

I want to mail an asp.net page from c#. well it is questioned widely and I saw bulk of questions like that on stackoverflow too. But I have few problems that I'm not getting the solutions

**What Itried** 
many example. below are few

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText( Server.MapPath("~/About.aspx"))) // Path to your 
      {                                                         // HTML file
        string fromAddress = "from@yahoo.com";
        string toAddress = "to@yahoo.com";
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
        myMail.Subject = "HTML Message";
        myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        myMail.Body = reader.ReadToEnd();  // Load the content from your file...
                //...

        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@yahoo.com", "password");
        smtp.Send(myMail);

        }
```

But this is giving me this output.
[image]

Well you noticed that it is without css.
 Can I mail an entire asp.net page or do I need to write my code in c# with inline css? Or do I need to create a control with a patern and send it?

Comment: you have to write inline css because every mail platform support simple hmtl...

Comment: try writing inline css or Link a globally hosted CSS file in your page

Comment: Thanks. so asp.net is not supported in mail platform. i need to write simple html

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send unprocessed aspx file. This cannot be successful. You need to process this page (I dont remember what method to use), and dont forget about inline css. So bassicaly you need a new page. And if you need a new page, you can do it with pure html, not in asp.

Comment: Thanks. so asp.net is not supported in mail platform. i need to write simple html